# Loss of touch pad function on laptop after upgrade

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, touchpad, hp

No touch pad function after upgrade. (as of 04/11/14) Using HP-255-G1 Notebook PC which came with Ubuntu 12.04 installed and have today upgraded to 14.04. Now I have to use a mouse on a laptop! Otherwise you would not be reading this post.
Is there a Terminal command that will rectify this?